# JS toggle event trigger not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have setup a responsive menu that on 480px or less the menu will collapse and show a button to click on and cause the menu to drop down. The problem I am having is, the menu will toggle down and immediately toggle back up. It won't stay open. I added a css to the js handler class called .nav-expanded to run after the toggle to allow the full menu to be displayed when opening up the screen to a larger dimension that 480px. If I remove the css from my stylesheet, or the code from the js, when I shrink the page to 480px or less, the new menu shows correctly, I can toggle open then close. However once I toggle close and widen my browser the menu remain hidden unless I refresh the browser.

The page is here http://skeeterz71.com/gothic/

My js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function(){

        jQuery("#first-nav").slideToggle(400, function(){

            jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '');

        });

    });

});
```

CSS in the stylesheet media query

```
.nav-expanded{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS for `.nav-expanded` is not getting applied since `#first-nav` styles are overriding it.

To give `.nav-expanded` the higher specificity add the following

```
#first-nav.nav-expanded {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this css in your jQuery code:

```
jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: This method actually reversed the problem. When open, closes right back up.

Comment: ya i understand thnaks